# Xamarin Forms Binding - access parent property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I cannot access the Page's ViewModel property in order to bind it to IsVisible Property. I can only bind it if I don't set the BindingContext. Is there a way I can access the page's viewmodel/root property while also setting the BindingContext?

Page XAML:

```
<eventViews:EventInfoWidget BindingContext="{Binding EventViewModel}" IsVisible="{Binding IsEventInfoWidgetEnabled}" />
<eventViews:AvailableShiftInfoWidget BindingContext="{Binding EventViewModel}" IsVisible="{Binding IsAvailableShiftInfoWidgetEnabled}"></eventViews:AvailableShiftInfoWidget>
```

ViewModel:

```
public EventViewModel EventViewModel { get; }
public bool IsEventInfoWidgetEnabled => _IsEventInfoWidgetEnabled.Value;
public bool IsAvailableShiftInfoWidgetEnabled => _IsAvailableShiftInfoWidgetEnabled.Value;
```

The IsVisibile Property can only be bind to the EventViewModel Object Properties, but I would like to bind it to the page's viewmodel

- IsEventInfoWidgetEnabled
- IsAvailableShiftInfoWidgetEnabled

Comment: Please explain your viewmodel. It has 3 properties? "EventViewModel", "_IsEventInfoWidgetEnabled" and "_IsAvailableShiftInfoWidgetEnabled"? Despite that, where is your INPC implementation? You should read into mvvm please.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a customized/non conventional mvvm implementation (project requirements). Yes the viewmodel has these 3 properties.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution, you have to specify the source and then set the path to the property.

First set the name of the page

```
<pages:AppContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
x:Name="ShiftPage">
```

After that just bind IsVisible Property to the right source

```
IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference ShiftPage}, Path=BindingContext.IsEventInfoWidgetEnabled }"
```