# How do you set a binding context in a ListView with respect to the outer binding context?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The code below should give you a pretty good idea of what I'm working with. Each `Widget` gets displayed in the `ListView`. But some of the widgets are "On Fire" and I would like to display their `StreetName` in red. The problem is the record of which widgets are on fire is kept in the `WidgetsViewModel`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
                xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                x:Class="SickProgram.Views.Pages.WidgetsPage"
                xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:SickProgram.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:WidgetsViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Widgets}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding StreetName}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

In a <s>perfect</s> world it would look something like:

```
<!- OnFire is a method in the WidgetsViewModel that takes in a widget Id and returns a color. ->
<Label Text="{Binding StreetName}" Color={Binding BindingContext.Parent.OnFire(BindingContext.Id)}/>
```

Also, I don't think using the selected item will get the job done. The display of on fire widgets should be independent from the display of the selected item.

Comment: Just found this which shows you how to access the parents binding context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798797/xamarin-forms-binding-access-parent-property.

Comment: if a widget is on fire, is the color always the same?

Comment: ideally the data binding will be live, so to speak, but in reality i don't think it matters for this application. The color of each widget's text is black by default but all of the on fire widgets should be red, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can tackle the problem about OnFire widgets having a separate color later.

You could define datatemplates and use a data template selector. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Each item that the list view is going to display will invoke the selector. if you can determine whether a widget is onFire by looking at some properties in the object. this method would work. if not let me know there are some other thoughts.

sorry I tried to format the output of this post.

Comment: That looks like the right thing to use. I'll have to get back to it on Monday because I'm still working out how to check the Id in the ValueConverter. Thanks for that link!

Comment: Goodluck, you are not able to cast the object to a particular type in the ValueConverter?

Comment: That would work np. Because of the way I have it written, though, I need to get the widgetId from the inner binding context and check that against the list of on fire widgets in the outer binding context. I can't figure out how to get both of them into the same method. It's a lot harder than I thought it would be. I'll be back. lol.

Comment: Look at passing the additional info you need via ConverterParameter. I am at work atm, I can send a link/example later if you can’t find anything.

Comment: Okay I gave up on doing it right. A `DataTemplate` would work except I still need to access the ViewModel to know which widgets are on fire and I cannot figure out how to get those two pieces of information together in the `DataTemplate`. My solution is to add an `IsOnFire` property to each widget in addition to keeping track of it in the ViewModel. It's kind of a bad design but I think I'm being forced into it. Lesson learned, I guess.